# How can I allow people to only kick members lower than their role with discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord.net

I'm trying to make a kick command using Python and the discord.py library, though I cannot figure out how to allow people to only be able to kick members lower than their role, so Moderators wouldn't be able to kick Admins.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egdu5.png)

Comment: Please don't include images of your code, format it with [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Adding images will make it difficult for it to show up when someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the `Member` object with a function called `top_role`

**An example code would be:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role: # Check if the role is below the authors role
        await ctx.send("You can only kick users with a lower role!")
        return
    else:
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
        await ctx.send(f"{member.id} got kicked with the reason: {reason}.")
```

Comment: @Had If it helped you/is working, make sure to accept the answer.

Comment: Moderators can kick other moderators with this, make the comparison a strict `>` if you don't want that to happen.

Answer (score -2):

Add all the moderators to a list and regular users to another list.

Like this;

```
string[] moderator = all moderators. 
string[] regularUsers = all regular users.
```

Comment: Instructions unclear, and this doesn't answer my question either...

Comment: I think @Videl is telling you to store all the moderator ids as a list and all admins as a list, so you know when a moderator is trying to kick an admin, wouldn't recommend doing this. It is very non-pythonic and will raise several problems later