# I've coded a discord bot to mute users using commands but the bot must not bot server mods but this code is muting mods too. How to fix it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have coded the bot to mute users using a command like .m @user but if I tag a moderator then the bot is muting the mods too. How to fix this code?

```
@bot.command(aliases=['m'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx,member:discord.Member):

    muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role(900024798585954325)

    await member.add_roles(muted_role)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="User Muted!", description=f"{member.mention} has been muted")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Check if the named user has a role higher than `muted_role`, a good post about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66693355/how-can-i-allow-people-to-only-kick-members-lower-than-their-role-with-discord-p/66694260#66694260

Comment: Thanks for your help my problem is solved :D